# Laravel - propery does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, collections, properties, instance

So I have a small Laravel car project and I have two separate tables, cars table and vehicle_infos table.
Here is my `CarsController@store`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'naslov' => 'required',
            'marka' => 'required',
            'model' => 'required',
            /*
            'kubikaza' => 'required',
            'zamajac' => 'required',
            'potrosnja' => 'required',
            'karoserija' => 'required',
            'kilometraza' => 'required',
            'godiste' => 'required',
            'gorivo' => 'required',
            'vlasnistvo' => 'required',
            'kilovata' => 'required',
            'konjska_snaga' => 'required',
            'emisiona_klasa' => 'required',
            'pogon' => 'required',
            'mjenjac' => 'required',
            'br_brzina_mjenjaca' => 'required',
            'velicina_felni' => 'required',
            'posjeduje_gume' => 'required',
            'br_vrata' => 'required',
            'br_sjedista' => 'required',
            'str_volana' => 'required',
            'klima' => 'required',
            'boja_spolj' => 'required',
            'boja_unutrasnj' => 'required',
            'materijal_unutrasnj' => 'required',
            'registracija' => 'required',
            'ostecenje' => 'required',
            'zamjena' => 'required',
            'sigurnost' => 'required',
            'oprema' => 'required',
            'stanje' => 'required',
            'nacin_finansiranja' => 'required',
            'nacin_prodaje' => 'required',
            'cijena' => 'required',
            'vrsta_cijene' => 'required',
            'opis_oglasa' => 'required',
            //'fotografije' => 'required',
            //'kontakt' => 'required',
            */
        ]);

        /*
        // Handle File Upload
        if($request->hasFile('fotografije')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('fotografije')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('fotografije')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('fotografije')->storeAs('public/slike_oglasa', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
        */

        $images=array();
        if($files=$request->file('fotografije')){
            foreach($files as $file){
                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('slike_oglasa',$name);
                $images[]=$name;
            }
        }

        $car = new Car;
        $car->naslov = $request->input('naslov');
        $car->marka = $request->input('marka');
        $car->model = $request->input('model');
        $car->kubikaza = $request->input('kubikaza');
        $car->zamajac = $request->input('zamajac');
        //$car->potrosnja = $request->input('potrosnja');
        $car->karoserija = $request->input('karoserija');
        $car->godiste = $request->input('godiste');
        $car->kilometraza = $request->input('kilometraza');
        $car->gorivo = $request->input('gorivo');
        $car->vlasnistvo = $request->input('vlasnistvo');
        $car->kilovata = $request->input('kilovata');
        $car->konjska_snaga = $request->input('konjska_snaga');
        $car->emisiona_klasa = $request->input('emisiona_klasa');
        $car->pogon = $request->input('pogon');
        $car->mjenjac = $request->input('mjenjac');
        $car->br_brzina_mjenjaca = $request->input('br_brzina_mjenjaca');
        $car->velicina_felni = $request->input('velicina_felni');
        $car->posjeduje_gume = $request->input('posjeduje_gume');
        $car->br_vrata = $request->input('br_vrata');
        $car->br_sjedista = $request->input('br_sjedista');
        $car->str_volana = $request->input('str_volana');
        $car->klima = $request->input('klima');
        $car->boja_spolj = $request->input('boja_spolj');
        $car->boja_unutrasnj = $request->input('boja_unutrasnj');
        $car->materijal_unutrasnj = $request->input('materijal_unutrasnj');
        $car->registracija = $request->input('registracija');
        $car->ostecenje = $request->input('ostecenje');
        $car->zamjena = $request->input('zamjena');
        $car->sigurnost = implode(',', $request->input('sigurnost'));
        $car->oprema = implode(',', $request->input('oprema'));
        $car->stanje = implode(',', $request->input('stanje'));
        $car->nacin_finansiranja = $request->input('nacin_finansiranja');
        $car->nacin_prodaje = $request->input('nacin_prodaje');
        $car->cijena = $request->input('cijena');
        $car->vrsta_cijene = $request->input('vrsta_cijene');
        $car->opis_oglasa = $request->input('opis_oglasa');
        //$car->user_id = 1;
        $car->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $car->fotografije =  implode("|", $images);
        $car->trajanje_oglasa = $request->input('trajanje_oglasa');
        $car->placeni_status = $request->input('placeni_status');

        if($car->trajanje_oglasa == 30){
            $car->to_datum_isteka = Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
        } else {
            $car->to_datum_isteka = Carbon::now()->addDays(60);
        }

        if($car->placeni_status == 0){
            $car->po_datum_isteka = Carbon::now();
        } else if($car->placeni_status == 1) {
            $car->po_datum_isteka = Carbon::now()->addDays(7);
        } else if($car->placeni_status == 2) {
            $car->po_datum_isteka = Carbon::now()->addDays(14);
        } else if($car->placeni_status == 3) {
            $car->po_datum_isteka = Carbon::now()->addDays(21);
        }
        //$car->kontakt = $request->input('kontakt');
        $car->save();

        $vehicleinfo = new VehicleInfo;
        //$vehicleinfo->urban = "Urban";
        $vehicleinfo->car_id = $car->id;
        $vehicleinfo->save();

        //ukupno oglasa od strane usera, skladistenje u ads table
        $ad = new Ad;
        $ad->car_id = $car->id;
        //$ad->user_id = 1;
        $ad->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $ad->save();

        return redirect('/cars');
}
```

My model `Car.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Car extends Model
{

    protected $table = "cars";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";

    protected $fillable = [
        'naslov', 'marka', 'model', 'kubikaza', 'zamajac', 'karoserija', 'godiste', 'kilometraza', 'br_brzina_mjenjaca',
        'gorivo', 'vlasnistvo', 'kilovata', 'konjska_snaga', 'emisiona_klasa', 'pogon', 'mjenjac', 'br_vrata', 'velicina_felni', 'posjeduje_gume',
        'br_sjedista', 'str_volana', 'klima', 'boja_spolj', 'boja_unutrasnj', 'materijal_unutrasnj', 'registracija', 'ostecenje',
        'zamjena', 'sigurnost', 'oprema', 'stanje', 'nacin_finansiranja', 'nacin_prodaje', 'cijena', 'vrsta_cijene', 'opis_oglasa', 'fotografije'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function vehicleinfo(){
        return $this->hasMany(VehicleInfo::class);
    }

    public function ad(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
    }
}
```

My model `VehicleInfo.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VehicleInfo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'vehicle_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['car_id', 'urban', 'extra_urban', 'combined', 'length', 'width', 'height'];

    public function car(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
}
```

So my `car_id` from `vehicle_infos` table is coming from `public function store()` of the `CarsController` and it automatically storing new data in `vehicle_infos` and that is okay.

But when I do `php artisan tinker` to check my relations it shows me error. So here is what I do in `php artisan tinker`:

First step: `$car = App\Car::find(4);` and it shows me all data for that car, then `$car->vehicleinfo` and it shows me all data from `vehicle_infos` table with `car_id` of `4`.

But when I do `$car->vehicleinfo->urban` ,for example, it shows me this error `Exception with message 'Property [urban] does not exist on this collection instance.'`. What do I do wrong? Please help me it frustating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing from the structure of your model, `cars` has many `vehicleinfo`. Doing $cars->vehicleinfo will give you a `collection` instance since it `hasMany` of it. Doing `$car->vehicleinfo->urban` will not work since there is no `urban` property on a `collection` instance.

Try doing:

```
$cars->vehicleinfo->first()->urban;
```

Or if you want all the urban properties of all the related vehicle infos:

```
$cars->vehicleinfo->pluck('urban') // returns an array of all the urban properties found
```

See [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections) for more methods.

Comment: I get it, thank you sir! We user first() for the first object in array if I get it right?

Comment: Yes! But its not exactly an array, its a `Collection`. Look "Laravel Collections" up. Laravel wraps the eloquent query in a `Collection`  for easier manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Hello can you try to replace `find()` by `find()->first()` or replace `$car->vehicleinfo->urban` by `$car->vehicleinfo[´urban’]`

And my eyes see this line `urban` is commented is normal the collection of instance `urban` not exist if you push data with the line commented. Normally sql will gold you you’re column urban is required no ?

This line have comment for `urban` 
`

```
    $vehicleinfo = new VehicleInfo;
    //$vehicleinfo->urban = "Urban";
    $vehicleinfo->car_id = $car->id;
    $vehicleinfo->save(); `
```